# Sorting multiple html tables with multiple sorts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I have several html tables on my page and I want to be able to sort them based on the value of one of their cell values. Here is an example of my tables

```
<div id="tables">
    <table class="sortable">
        <tr>
            <td>Comic Book Name</td>
            <td id="comic">Batman</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Main Character</td >
            <td ="character">Bruce Wayne</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hero Name</td>
            <td id="hero">Batman</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Published</td>
            <td id="publish">05/01/1940</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="sortable">
        <tr>
            <td>Comic Book Name</td>
            <td id="comic">Green Arrow</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Main Character</td >
            <td ="character">Oliver Queen</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hero Name</td>
            <td id="hero">Green Arrow</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Published</td>
            <td id="publish">11/01/1941</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I am providing the following drop down to allow users to filter.

```
<select id="OrderBy">
 <option selected="selected" value="comic">Comic Name</option>
 <option value="character">Character Name</option>
 <option value="hero">Hero Name</option>
 <option value="publish">Earliest Publish Date</option>
</select>
```

My hopes here are to sort the tables alphabetically by Comic book name when they choose Comic Name, alphabetically by Character Name when they select character name etc. etc.

Here is the javascript/jquery I have come up with so far. I'm sure this could be done better but I'm new to Javascript and Jquery.

```
$('#OrderBy').on('change', function () {
    _order = $('#OrderBy').val();
    switch (_order) {
        case "comic":
            $('#sortable').sort(function () {

            });
            break;
        case "character":
            $('#sortable').children().sort(function (a, b) {
            });
            break;
        case "publish":
            $('#sortable').sort(function () {
            });
            break;
        case "publish":
            $('#sortable').sort(function () {
                if ($(b).children().find('#Hours').text() - $(a).children().find('#publish').text() <= 0) {
                    return $(a) - $(b);
                }
                return $(b) - $(a);
            });
            break;
    }
});
```

Everywhere I look someone suggests Sorttables or tableSorter but I've only seen how they would work for a single table whose rows are being sorted. I know what everyone is thinking at this point, don't use tables this way. My problem is there is already a bunch of jquery and javascript supporting the tables and I'm not experienced enough in the languages to re-write all of that.

I like the idea of pushing everything onto a stack as described [here](http://www.wrichards.com/blog/2009/02/jquery-sorting-elements/) but I always generated an error about how my array/stack was not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should not put several times the same id, but use classes instead:

```
<div id="tables">

    <table class="sortable">
        <tr>
            <td>Comic Book Name</td>
            <td class="comic">Green Arrow</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Main Character</td >
            <td class="character">Oliver Queen</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hero Name</td>
            <td class="hero">Green Arrow</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Published</td>
            <td class="publish">11/01/1941</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="sortable">
        <tr>
            <td>Comic Book Name</td>
            <td class="comic">Batman</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Main Character</td >
            <td class="character">Bruce Wayne</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hero Name</td>
            <td class="hero">Batman</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Published</td>
            <td class="publish">05/01/1940</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

For your problem, I would use the native `Array.prototype.sort` method

```
var tables = [];
var $tables = $("table.sortable");
var container = $("#tables");
// this is the only specific case, as the date does not start by the year
// it will be used to sort by publish date
function sortByDate(a, b) {
    return new Date(a.publish).getTime() - new Date(b.publish).getTime();
}

function sortTables(order) {
    var sort;
    if (order === "publish") {
        tables = tables.sort(sortByDate);
    } else {
        tables = tables.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a[order] < b[order] ? -1 : 1;
        });
    }
    tables.forEach(function(data,i) {
        tables[i].$el.detach()
        container.append(tables[i].el);
    });
}

function init() {
    //populate the tables array that will be sorted
    $tables.each(function(i, val) {
        var $this = $(this);
        tables.push({
            $el: $this,
            el: this,
            comic: $this.find(".comic").text(),
            character: $this.find(".character").text(),
            hero: $this.find(".hero").text(),
            publish: $this.find(".publish").text()
        });
    });
    $("#OrderBy").on("change", function(event) {
        sortTables(event.currentTarget.value);
    });
    //by default sort by Hero
    sortTables("hero");
}
init();
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help. Everything seems to be tracking right when I add some console.log statements but any reason it would hide all of my tables when sorting them? If I can verify that's not a bug in the code you provided I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: any reason it would hide all of my tables when sorting them ----> `$tables.detach();` but you cannot sort anything if you don't remove then add that thing.

Comment: I'll check it out again tonight. You're awesome and I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Primarily, Sort can't happen when you have data in two different tables. To make it possible, you need to put id to them, not just classes because your primary issue isn't CSS. Again, if you put same id to different contents, it can't be spotted specifically. So, debugged code would be:

```
<div id="tables">
<table id="tbl1" class="sortable">
    <tr>
        <td>Comic Book Name</td>
        <td class="comic">Batman</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Main Character</td >
        <td class="character">Bruce Wayne</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hero Name</td>
        <td class="hero">Batman</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Published</td>
        <td class="publish">05/01/1940</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table id="tbl2" class="sortable">
    <tr>
        <td>Comic Book Name</td>
        <td class="comic">Green Arrow</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Main Character</td >
        <td class="character">Oliver Queen</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hero Name</td>
        <td class="hero">Green Arrow</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Published</td>
        <td class="publish">11/01/1941</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Your drop-down menu(filter box) is properly defined. Now, in js code, there are some syntactical mistakes.
like, 'class' identifier is '.', 'id' identifier is '#', you used '#' instead of '.' some places :

```
switch (_order) {
    case "comic":
        $('#sortable').sort(function () {});
```

debugged code would be:

```
$('#OrderBy').on('change', function () {
_order = $('#OrderBy').val();
switch (_order) {
    case "comic":
        $('.sortable').sort(function () {});
        break;
    case "character":
        $('.sortable').children().sort(function (a, b) {
        });
        break;
    case "publish":
        $('.sortable').sort(function () {
        });
        break;
    case "publish":
        $('.sortable').sort(function () {
            if ($(b).children().find('#Hours').text() - $(a).children().find('#publish').text() <= 0) {
                return $(a) - $(b);
            }
            return $(b) - $(a);
        });
        break;
}});
```

There's no official table sort() function jquery library. It would work for array only, but you won't have any array here.
So we make a sort function on our own. We can name it 'sortTable()'. The code for this should be:

```
<!--   -------------------------------------------------------------- -->
<!-- Secondary functions -->

<!-- Creates a new table to display the sorted Table -->

function createEmptyTable(){
    var outerDiv = document.createElement('div');
    outerDiv.setAttribute('id','ResultTable');
    var innerTable = doucment.createElement('table');
    innerTable.setAttribute('id','sortedTable'); 
    var newRows = new Array();
    var recordIndex = document.getElementsByClassName('comic');
    innerTable.innerHTML = "<tr> <th>Comic Book Name </th> <th>Main Character</th> <th>Hero Name</th> <th>Published</th> </tr>";
    for(var i=0; i<recordIndex.Length;i++){
        newRows[i]= document.createElement('tr');
        outerDiv.appendChild(innerTable).appendChild(newRows[i]);
        }
    }

<!--     -------------------------------------------------------------  -->

<!-- function to find out in which table chosen filter belongs -->

function recordSearch(keyWord){
    var sortableTables = document.getElementsByClassName('sortable');
    for( var i=0; i<sortableTables.length;i++){
        if($(sortableTables[i]).find(keyword)){
        return sortableTable[i];
    }
        }

<!--      -------------------------------------------------------------    -->

<!-- Primary function to sort the Table -->

function sortTable(filtered_option){

<!-- first we delete any existing sorted table -->

    if(document.getElementById('ResultTable')){
        var existingSortedTable = document.getElementbyId('ResultTable');
        existingSortedTable.removeChild(document.getElementById('sortedTable');
    }

<!-- now we create new table & put the result -->

    createEmptyTable();
    var comicNames = document.getElementsByClassName('comic');
    var characterNames = document.getElementsByClassName('character');
    var heroNames = document.getElementsByClassName('hero');
    var publishDates = document.getElementsByClassName('publish');

    switch (filtered_option) {

    case 'comic' :
        var sortedComicNames = comicNames.sort();
        for(var i=0;i<sortedComicNames.length;i++){
            var foundRecord = recordSearch(sortedComicNames[i]);
            var allFields = foundRecord.getElementByTagName('tr').getElementsByClassName('td');
            var emptyRows = document.getElementById('sortedTable').getElementsByTagName('tr');
            for(var j=0;j<allFields.length;j++){
                emptyRows[i+1].innerHTML = "<td>" + allFields[j].value + "</td>" ;
        }}
    break;

    case 'character' :
        var sortedCharacterNames= characterNames.sort();
        for(var i=0;i<characterNames.length;i++){
            var foundRecord = recordSearch(sortedCharacterNames[i]);
            var allFields = foundRecord.getElementByTagName('tr').getElementsByClassName('td');
            var emptyRows = document.getElementById('sortedTable').getElementsByTagName('tr');
            for(var j=0;j<allFields.length;j++){
                emptyRows[i+1].innerHTML = "<td>" + allFields[j].value + "</td>" ;
        }}
    break;

    case 'hero' :
        var sortedHeroNames= heroNames.sort();
        for(var i=0;i<heroNames.length;i++){
            var foundRecord = recordSearch(heroNames[i]);
            var allFields = foundRecord.getElementByTagName('tr').getElementsByClassName('td');
            var emptyRows = document.getElementById('sortedTable').getElementsByTagName('tr');
            for(var j=0;j<allFields.length;j++){
                emptyRows[i+1].innerHTML = "<td>" + allFields[j].value + "</td>" ;
        }}
    break;

    case 'publish' :
        var sortedPublishedDates= publishedDates.sort();
        for(var i=0;i<publishedDates.length;i++){
            var foundRecord = recordSearch(publishedDates[i]);
            var allFields = foundRecord.getElementByTagName('tr').getElementsByClassName('td');
            var emptyRows = document.getElementById('sortedTable').getElementsByTagName('tr');
            for(var j=0;j<allFields.length;j++){
                emptyRows[i+1].innerHTML = "<td>" + allFields[j].value + "</td>" ;
        }}
    break;  
    }
}
<!--    --------------------------------------------------------------------    -->
```

Put them together and Try. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Don't you think that your `sortTable` function is over complicated ?

Comment: I did what I had to do. The problem is there are multi-tables, contains homogeneous record. It's difficult to sort multi-tables to a single table where applied variable filtering options(e.g sort by character name, etc). If the sort occurred with only attribute(filtering option) then the logic is simple. I made this procedure on asker's table structure priority. if table structure changes function would not work!

Comment: see my answer...
I'm just trying to be constructive, you parse the dom everytime you call `sortTable()`, recreate everything, override variables, extensively use loops for nothing and your switch/case is not useful at all because you do 4 times the same thing...

Comment: I've no comment on that, you have a good constructive table. But what you'll do, if there's more than two table, call bubble sort with whole code?

Comment: Take it easy, man. I didn't want to hurt you... I was just pointing out that you could optimize your code, that's all.

Comment: I appreciate your input. While this does work for sorting I think I confused you on my desired input. I wanted the tables to stay separate but sorted in respect to the others. You earned an upvote from me though.

Comment: Ya, it's bit of complex, because I used formal methods. I'm novice in web designing. I saw you were arranging data in different tables, I thought you would do more like that. So I made the function such that it would take any number of table then sort and put them in a single table. It's like putting different fruits in mixer and get cocktail as result.